# Why different syntax for nullable reference and value types?

Tags: c#, nullable-reference-types

Please consider the following .NET6 snippet which attempts to show a difference in syntax for handling nullable reference types and nullable value types.

```
List<string?> nstrings = new();

// OK
IEnumerable<string> strings = nstrings.Where(s => s != null).Select(s => s!);



List<double?> ndoubles = new();

//OK 
IEnumerable<double> doubles = ndoubles.Where(d => d != null).Select(d => d!.Value); 

// Bad!
// Cannot implicitly convert type 
// 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<double?>' to 
// 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<double>'. 
// An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) [nullable]csharp(CS0266)
IEnumerable<double> doubles2 = ndoubles.Where(d => d != null).Select(d => d!);
```

By saying

> The language already has a notion of – and a syntax for – nullable value types. The analogy between the two would make the language addition conceptually easier, and linguistically simpler.

NET Blog's [Introducing Nullable Reference Types in C#](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/nullable-reference-types-in-csharp/) in my view acknowledges that it would be better if the syntax was identical.

Why could not syntax for *nullable value types* be made like syntax for *nullable reference types* (or vice versa)?

When enabling nullable reference types in legacy code changes are practically always required and this weakens the backward compatibility argument significantly (it's the first that comes to mind).

Comment: You might get an answer from https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues But I don't think "backward compatibility" is ever a factor to be considered here in language design.

Comment: what does `s!` and `d!` mean?

Comment: @LeiYang `!` is the [null-forgiving operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-forgiving)

Comment: (1/2) If you turn off nullable checking for reference types, the code will still compile and run the same, because the nullable checking does not change the IL code generated (ignoring any metadata). If they introduced `!` as a syntax for accessing the `.Value` part of a `Nullable<T>` what would you want to happen if you turn off nullable checking? Because your choices then are: (1) make the use of `!` in that situation cause a compiler error, (2) ignore it (changing the code generated and likely causing knock-on compile errors) or (3) always use it regardless of the setting.

Comment: (2/2) None of these choices match the usage for nullable reference types, so it could be confusing to introduce this new syntax which looks a lot like the null-forgiving operator, but which in fact is quite different. I imagine this would preclude such a feature, but only the language designers would know for sure.